# Does oracle support nested result sets?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Forgive me if this doesn't make sense.  I haven't done SQL in years and years.  Getting my feet wet again so please correct me if my assumptions here are wrong.

From what I recall, SQL Server (or perhaps it was an ADO.NET thing) had a neat feature where you could nest a subset of 'child' rows in a parent-child relation along with their corresponding parent row, as a nested result set for that parent row.

For instance, if you had the following three tables...

- Orders (ID, Name)
- Products (ID, Name)
- OrderDetails (Order_ID, Product_ID)

So as an example, say you had ten orders, each with say five items. A standard join would return fifty rows.

What I'm referring to is a feature that would give me back *ten* rows--one per order--then as you were cursoring through those results, you would ask for the nested results for that row (i.e. essentially a second cursor over just the products in that order.)

Does Oracle have any such feature/capability?

Comment: Are you referring to an inner join?

Comment: No... for instance, I'm cursoring through the results of the orders. If there are ten orders, I have ten records, but as I am on record 1, I can get the sub-records for order 1 without having to make a second call.  Make sense?

Comment: Then perhaps you are referring to the GUI tool used to view the result set. Maybe this was an option in MS Access but I have not ever seen something like this in SSMS (sql server management studio). Perhaps the Oracle management interface does allow it but I assume probably not...

Comment: No, it was not a GUI tool. It was a nested result set that you could access through the returned objects. I'm wondering if it was a feature of ADO.NET and not the database.

Comment: You might want to look into CAST(MULTISET ....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CURSOR` expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions005.htm):

```sql
SELECT id AS orderid,
       CURSOR(
         SELECT p.id,
                p.name
         FROM   OrderedProducts op
                INNER JOIN Products p
                ON ( op.products_id = p.id )
         WHERE  op.orders_id = o.id
       )
FROM   orders o
```

Cursor expressions are not supported by many interfaces but you should be able to make it work using Java through JDBC and maybe some others.

---

Another alternative is to use Collections and Object types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE product_type AS OBJECT(
  id   NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(200)
);
/

CREATE TYPE product_table AS TABLE OF product_type;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT id AS Order_Id,
       CAST(
         MULTISET (
           SELECT  product_type( P.id, P.name )
           FROM    OrderDetails OD
           JOIN    Products P
           ON      OD.Product_Id = P.Id
           WHERE   OD.Order_Id   = O.Id
         )
         AS product_table
       ) AS products
FROM   Orders O;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bed69e098dfaed86171673ea87152531) (db<>fiddle successfully runs the query; although it doesn't know how to display the collection in final result set so it doesn't show any rows)

---

Or you could use XML:

```sql
SELECT id AS order_id,
       ( SELECT XMLELEMENT(
                  "Products",
                  XMLAGG(
                    XMLElement(
                      "Product",
                      XMLFOREST(
                        p.id AS "ProductID",
                        p.name AS "ProductName"
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
         FROM   OrderDetails OD
         JOIN   Products P
         ON     OD.Product_Id = P.Id
         WHERE  OD.Order_Id   = O.Id
       ) AS products
FROM   Orders o
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ORDER_ID | PRODUCTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
> -------: | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>        1 | <Products><Product><ProductID>202</ProductID><ProductName>car</ProductName></Product></Products>                                                                                                                                                              
>        2 | <Products><Product><ProductID>201</ProductID><ProductName>orange</ProductName></Product><Product><ProductID>202</ProductID><ProductName>car</ProductName></Product><Product><ProductID>203</ProductID><ProductName>airplane</ProductName></Product></Products>
> ```

Or JSON:

```sql
SELECT id AS order_id,
       ( SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                  JSON_OBJECT(
                    'id' VALUE p.id,
                    'name' VALUE p.name
                  )
                )
         FROM   OrderDetails OD
         JOIN   Products P
         ON     OD.Product_Id = P.Id
         WHERE  OD.Order_Id   = O.Id
       ) AS products
FROM   Orders o
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ORDER_ID | PRODUCTS                                                                         
> -------: | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>        1 | [{"id":202,"name":"car"}]                                                        
>        2 | [{"id":201,"name":"orange"},{"id":202,"name":"car"},{"id":203,"name":"airplane"}]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=919fd73ca388b9d42ae72c7b42b0391c)*

Comment: Apologies for editing your answer, but I tried to show the code here and comments mangled it, so I edited your answer so I can paste it there.  Did I make a mistake in that code?  It's throwing an error. (As I said there, please feel free to delete/revert your answer once you take a look.)

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe I don't have a local instance of Oracle to test the cursor expression at the moment. Trying it on Oracle's LiveSQL gives a different error (probably relating to displaying the output rather than an error in the query but its difficult to debug what is an interface issue and what is an error in the query) and db<>fiddle won't run the expression. I've got cursor expressions working through JDBC before. I've added another example using Collections and Object types (again, it is definitely supported through Java and JDBC).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server had no such a feature.  The only way to return "shaped" data from a SQL Server query is to use [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) or [JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) as the output.

You can return multiple, separate resultsets from a single batch request or stored procedure call.

So the batch

```
select * from orders where id = @id
select * from order_details where order_id = @id
```

will simply return two seperate resultsets, which the client sees in-order.

Oracle does have nested cursors, but I'm not sure how widely used they are or which client APIs support them.

> It was a nested result set that you could access through the returned objects. I'm wondering if it was a feature of ADO.NET and not the database.

ADO.NET has the [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders) which stores related data from multiple tables in-memory.  But the data is always loaded and written back with separate queries per table.  And both ADO.NET DataSets, and the newer .Net data access API Entity Framework work with Oracle.

Going even further back into the dark ages, there was ADO [Data Shaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/data-shaping-overview?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Yeah, definitely wasn't multiple recordists in a batch.  This was distinctly navigating through the 'parent' rows, which then gave you the child rows.  Perhaps it was data shaping as you said, but even so, something has to populate those result sets, no? Point is I remember it was a single call to the database, so if you had 1000 parent rows, each returning say 5 child rows, it wasn't 1001 calls. It was one call that returned 1000 rows and as you went through each, you could get the 'child' rows for that parent.  Do you have an example? Better yet, do you have a phone #? lol

Comment: Re your link... "Regular SQL allows you to retrieve data using JOIN syntax, but this can be inefficient and unwieldy because redundant parent data is repeated in each record [...] Data shaping can relate a single parent record in the parent Recordset to multiple child records in the child Recordset, avoiding the redundancy of a JOIN." EXACTLY!  That's what I remember.  So SHAPE was something on the client access layer, not SQL Server?  You couldn't execute SHAPE directly in Transact-SQL?  Perhaps that's what I incorrectly remembered as being a feature of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but - it looks like an ordinary join. See an example:

```
with 
-- sample data
orders (id, name) as
  (select 1, 'Order 1' from dual union all
   select 2, 'Order 2' from dual 
  ),
products (id, name) as
  (select 200, 'apple' from dual union all
   select 201, 'orange' from dual union all
   select 202, 'car' from dual union all
   select 203, 'airplane' from dual
  ),
orderedproducts (orders_id, products_id) as
  (select 1, 202 from dual union all
   select 2, 201 from dual union all
   select 2, 202 from dual union all
   select 2, 203 from dual
  )
-- query you need (I think)  
select o.id oid, o.name oname, p.id, p.name
from orders o join orderedproducts op on op.orders_id = o.id
              join products p on p.id = op.products_id
where 
  -- get everything for order ID = 2
  o.id = 2
order by o.id, p.id;

        ID NAME            ID NAME
---------- ------- ---------- --------
         2 Order 2        201 orange
         2 Order 2        202 car
         2 Order 2        203 airplane
```

If that's not *it*, could you post what you really expect from it? You know - desired result?

---

If you want to *skip* repeating values from the `orders` table, that depends on tool you use. In SQL*Plus, you'd `BREAK` on those columns, e.g.

```
SQL> break on oid on oname
SQL>
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  orders (id, name) as
  4    (select 1, 'Order 1' from dual union all
<snip>
 23  where
 24    -- get everything for order ID = 2
 25    o.id = 2
 26  order by o.id, p.id;

       OID ONAME           ID NAME
---------- ------- ---------- --------
         2 Order 2        201 orange
                          202 car
                          203 airplane

SQL>
```

Or, if you use some reporting tool (such as Oracle Reports Builder or even Apex' Interactive or Classic reports), they also have such a capability.

---

If that's still not "it", is PL/SQL an option for you? Some call it "stored procedures" (though, that's not exactly what it is, but "procedure" is easier to understand than "PL/SQL"). There you have different options, such as cursors and loops.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean because if I am returning all columns from 'Orders' then they would all be repeated in the results.  I am saying there is a one-to-one row-to-order, but for each order row, there is a *nested* result set that has just the products in that order.  Make sense?

Comment: I added some more info. Have a look, please.

Comment: Clarifying, there would only be one row for the order, but then you would get essentially a second (nested) cursor that would have three rows for the products.  So think of it like one cursor for the parent rows, then a second cursor for the nested rows for each parent.

Comment: (Sorry, I have to go offline. I'll be probably back tomorrow).

Comment: Hey... this looks like it may be heading in the right direction, but can you edit your answer to just show the SQL itself instead of the line numbers/prompt, etc.? That should make it more clear.  Also, this looks like it's outputting to a terminal.  What do the returned results look like? How do you iterate over them?

Comment: I posted query without line numbers. The second example (with BREAK) is meaningful only in SQL*Plus, so I left it "as is". Also, I added another possibility - PL/SQL, if it *is* an option for you.